# SELECT don't recieve data in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to set connection in UDP. The first time i send something heare the select detects data. However on the second time the select don't return anything. I've  checked that the message it's send correctly.

Do u know where it's the error?

Thanks.

```
int T_HaArribatAlgunaCosa(const int *LlistaSck, int LongLlistaSck)
{
    fd_set read_fd_set;
    int i, max_fd_value, max = 0;
    
    // Add keyboard and socket into the set
    FD_ZERO(&read_fd_set);
    for (i = 0; i < LongLlistaSck; i++) {
        FD_SET(LlistaSck[i], &read_fd_set);
        if (max < LlistaSck[i]) {
            max = LlistaSck[i];
        }
    }

    max_fd_value = max;

    if(select(max_fd_value+1, &read_fd_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1) {
        return -1; // ERROR
    }

    // See which fd is set
    for (i = 0; i < LongLlistaSck; i++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(LlistaSck[i], &read_fd_set)) {
            printf("Ha arribat alguna cosa");
            return LlistaSck[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (and without an empty line every other line, if humanly possible).